# Line plot with Canvas using Jquery slider

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, slider

I am tying to use a jquery slider to plot a line on a canvas when I click a button.
I dont know how and where to make the value from the slider a variable that changes with the slider, it just stays with the initial slider value.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:100,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        step: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
    a=$( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>

function myFunction()
{
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.moveTo(a,50);
    ctx.lineTo(b,0);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To incrementally draw a line between 2 points you need to interpolate XY values between the points**

[image]

```
// define the line
var startX=50;
var startY=150;
var endX=250;
var endY=50;
var dx=endX-startX;
var dy=endY-startY;

function lineXY(percent) {

    // find the XY that’s a percentage of the way between start and end points
    percent/=100;
    currentX = startX + dx*percent;
    currentY = startY + dy*percent;

    // and then draw the line
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
    ctx.lineTo(currentX,currentY);
    ctx.stroke();

}
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9tU9E/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <style>
      body{ background-color: ivory; }
      #wrapper{ position:relative; }
      canvas{ position:absolute; left:40px; top:5px; border:1px solid red;}
      #amount{ position:absolute; left:1px; top:5px; margin-bottom:15px; width:23px; border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; }
      #slider-vertical{ position:absolute; left:5px; top:40px; width:15px; height:225px; border:0px; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>

  $(function() {

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      value: 50,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        lineXY(ui.value);
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value" ) );


    var startX=50;
    var startY=150;
    var endX=250;
    var endY=50;
    var dx=endX-startX;
    var dy=endY-startY;

    ctx.strokeStyle="green";
    ctx.lineWidth=5;

    lineXY(50);

    // 
    function lineXY(percent) {
        percent/=100;
        currentX = startX + dx*percent;
        currentY = startY + dy*percent;

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
        ctx.lineTo(currentX,currentY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(startX,startY,5,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(endX,endY,5,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

    }



  });   // end $(function(){});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="amount" />
        <div id="slider-vertical"></div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```